# Is there way to route to home from a separate app hosted in a sub directory?

Tags: vue.js, nginx

I have a vue js webapp which is hosted in `www.example.com/app` and the home page of the application is hosted in `www.example.com` as a separate vue js app using `nginx`. whenever the user hits, `www.example.com/app/home` I want to redirect to `www.example.com`.

right now I am doing,

```
//router.js 
{
      path: "/home",
      beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        window.location.href = "https://www.example.com";
      }
    },
```

inside the route.js of `example.com/app` to achieve this. But in the localhost and the dev environment, this method won't work for obvious reasons. Is there a more convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can redirect with relative URL.

```
window.location.href = "/";
```